# Write txt file using my foreign language shows strange characters

Tags: c#

I'm trying to export a txt file using my local language characters.
If i will change txt file font to "**Terminal**" it shows:

[image]
In other fonts it works nice. But i need terminal cause i need to send it in a fiscal printer.
Otherwise it doesnt work.

Here is how i'm export it to txt:

```
string test = "ΤΡΟΦΙΜΑ";
        System.IO.StreamWriter SW = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Log.txt", false,Encoding.Default);
        SW.Write(test);
        SW.Close();
```

Comment: There are two entirely separate things to consider here: a) the encoding (I'd almost always suggest using `Encoding.UTF8` rather than `Encoding.Default`); b) whether the font you're using supports the characters you want to use. It's not clear to me what your "fiscal printer" is, but you should find out more about what it supports.

Comment: Same thing if i will use utf8

Comment: I'm afraid we still won't be able to help you without knowing more about what you mean by "fiscal printer". Is this a piece of hardware? Do you have a link to any documentation?

Comment: I thing in english called cashier. Yes its a hardware machine which takes txt and prints my items. https://www.google.gr/search?q=ics+i57&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4ptDs38vaAhUDxqYKHdLkDXAQ_AUICygC&biw=1920&bih=900#imgrc=V84BJH-NBjcuUM:

Comment: So please link to the documentation for that *very specific* piece of hardware. Different machines will have different capabilities etc.

Comment: It doesnt have to do with documentation but with terminal font in txt. How should i convert it for reading my local language in txt's terminal font? In Utf?Bytes?Binary?

Comment: No, I'm asking for documentation for the hardware in question so that I can try to help you. I'm skeptical that the Windows Terminal font is what it actually uses. Note that fonts and encodings are pretty separate concepts. But if you don't want to link to the documentation for the hardware you're using, I'm not going to be able to help you.

Comment: Terminal Font doesn't support Unicode. Open it in the Charater Map (charmap.exe) and see what characters are supported in your local codepage. UTF-8 won't help, for the said reason. You might have to find another pixelled font that supports cyrillic as a substitute. There are a number aroud, also free.